# Synapse Server less Pool writing data back to ADLS Gen-2 using CETAS >> Permissions issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, serverless, azure-synapse

Use case-
After learning that AD Passthrough is not working as expected on Synapse Serverless pool with ADLS Gen-2 ; I am trying to use traditional method of creating external tables on Serverless Pool and granting READ ONLY access to users to a set of tales and enable WRITE BACK option to another ADLS Gen-2 container using CETAS option .

Looks like I am stuck there as well - to move forward.

I have tried to explain my scenario in below image.

[image]

Now - I have 5 external tables on a database where I have a READ ONLY access to the schema's where those table exists.
I wanted to create few more tables - which ideally does a JOIN between those 5 tables and aggregates the data and writes back to ADLS Gen-2 for reporting/data science purpose.

What access should I grant for WRITE back purpose ?
I tried creating new schema and granting ALTER, CONTROL, SELECT access to that schema along with CREATE TABLE access at database level . I dont want to grant more access to database level - as it has data scoped credential having managed identity referenced- which will grant full access on ROC container objects.

```
Grant select on SCHEMA ::sandbox to sls_svc ;

Grant ALTER on SCHEMA ::sandbox to sls_svc ;

GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[sandbox ] TO [sls_svc];

Grant CREATE TABLE to sls_svc;


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sanbox.revenue-by-month
WITH (
    LOCATION = '/ROW/revenue-by-month/',
    DATA_SOURCE = ADLS-ROW,  
    FILE_FORMAT = EF_PARQUET
)  
AS
SELECT      * from table1;
```

all users in sls_svc role has STORAGE DATA CONTRIBUTOR access on READ-WRITE-CONTAINER (ROW)

Below are the error messages I am getting

[image]

I also tried creating a new database. hoping that i can grant full access on that database - so that cross DB query can work - but I am out of luck there as well.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRANT CONNECT to the database that was created
+
GRANT DDL_ADMIN access

resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have correctly set permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-overview?tabs=impersonation#permissions

Are you sure that you can successfully execute just select statement and that the issue is not in SELECT part?

Comment: yes, the select statement is working fine . I had re-run the select statement and that retrieved the results.